# From js.erb file function call

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want a function in abc.js.erb like this:

```
function add_times(s){
    <%num = 0%>
    if(s == "Twice"){
      <%num = 2%>
    }else if(s == "Three times"){
      <%num = 3%>
    }else if(s == "Four times"){
      <% num = 4%>
    }else if(s == "Five times"){
      <%num = 5%>
    }else if(s == "Six times"){
      <%num = 6%>
    }else{
      <%num = 0%>
    }

    <% num.times do |n| %>
      $("#div_id").append('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "abc/xyz", :locals=>{:n=>n})%>')
    <% end %>

}
```

I want to pass a string to this function. Depending upon the value I want to render a partial with index number. This is not working. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why `num` needs to be a erb variable. Pure javascript should work out. If any of the partials need specific information depending on the number you could use spans and css to target these (hint: `nth`) and use javascript to alter the content. What I mean is that you render the partial when rendering the page and don't even resort to AJAX but straight Javascript.